Complex Exponentiation
As the title says! Raise one complex number to the power of another.
(a+bi)^(c+di)(using the principal branch of the complex logarithm)
Requires four inputs a, b, c, d. You can combine a, b, c, d into respective vectors/arrays (e.x. C([a, b], [c, d]))
Built-in complex arithmetic is not allowed. Code the solution yourself!
(Built-in functions are any functions that perform arithmetic on complex vectors. e.x. quaternions, complex libraries, languages where complex numbers are a type. If your language does not have an only-real type then arithmetic operators can only be used on the reals.)
Functions are treated as the program:
function x(arg){
    ...
    return output;
}

is the same as
arg = getInput();
...
print(output);

Smallest byte length wins.
EXAMPLES:

(1+1.5i)^(2+2.5i) ≈ −0.266-0.082i
(e+1i)^(π+1i) ≈ −11.213 + 16.386i
(1+1i)^(1+1i) ≈ 0.274 + 0.584i
(-1+i)^(1+i) ≈ -0.121 + 0.057i


Does this answer your question? Exponent of complex numbers

@KaiBurghardt The linked challenge is about complex numbers raised to the power of an integer.

Banning built-ins is usually frowned upon (it used to be acceptable in the past); see here or here

Arnauld is correct here. The thing you linked only raises it to the power of an integer. This challenge includes a complex power (which is quite a bit harder to do).

By banning built-ins i mean that if your language supports complex numbers (i'm sure there are some that do) you can't just use a function like complex1 ^ complex2 or complexExp(complex1, complex2). You actually have to code the math behind it. I mostly want people to think through the problem as the math behind it is quite interesting and fun.

I think this problem is not well defined. The complex exponentiation is multi valued, and there is not a standard way to select the branch cut.

What do you mean by that? I can tell you there is at least one formula that can solve any (a+bi)^(c+di) problem in a way a computer can run (it does use trig functions though). Any number that does not use either the real or complex part (e.x. 3 or 4.5i) can just be expressed with zeros (3+0i, 0+4.5i).

@ThePlaneGuy45 I think it is multivalued because it depends on the argument of the base, which is itself multivalued, as you can see here

in fact, if you ask WolframAlpha for a complex exponential it gives a result using the principal branch, and then gives a generic form which depends on a parameter

Updated the question to use the principal branch of the complex logarithm. (this is what Wolfram Alpha uses for it's primary answer)

I recommend adding tests with bases in quadrants other than the first to check that the solution is using atan2 instead of normal arctangent, for example (-1+i)^(1+i)

In regards to Banning Built Ins, I'd personally recommend allowing them, but encourage users to also post a non-built-in answer in the same language. Banning Built-ins is otherwise a Non-observable restriction.

I've closed this since there is no observable criteria for determining if an answer uses "Built-in complex arithmetic". I will be happy to reopen this once this point is clarified.

Edited post to hopefully make it clearer. If it needs any additional information I can add.

Note that some languages support complex numbers natively, without complex libraries or a complex data type

In those cases operators can only be used on the reals.

I think it is very clear. Even if your language supports complex arithmetic, at no point in your computation may any value be complex.

@Adám The spec is certainly clear, but that's still non-observable. Which goes against the current consensus.

@Arnauld What consensus? That high scored answer only says This leaves requiring "no built-ins" as a point of contention. I'd be fine with either banning them or not.

@Adám The meta question was about banning non-observable requirements globally. My understanding is that the part you quoted applies to such a global ban. But it suggests disallowing non-observable requirements for pure code golf -- as clearly mentioned in the title of the answer as well. (Now, I agree that we probably need more explicit rules.)

JavaScript (ES7), 94 bytes
Returns [real, img].
This is essentially the formula used by doubleunary, except I'm computing \$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\$ (with hypot) instead of \$a^2+b^2\$ to get rid of both divisions by 2.
with(Math)f=(a,b,c,d,p=atan2(b,a))=>[cos,sin].map(g=>g(c*p+d*log(h=hypot(a,b)))*h**c/exp(d*p))

Try it online!

Google Sheets, 91 bytes
=let(s,A1^2+B1^2,a,atan2(A1,B1),r,s^(C1/2)/exp(D1*a),u,C1*a+D1*ln(s)/2,{r*cos(u),r*sin(u)})

Put the four coefficients in cells A1:D1 and the formula in cell E1.
Returns the real and imaginary parts as a two-element array. To get an actual complex number, replace the final { array expression } with complex() (98 bytes) or text() (119 bytes, see the edits). The latter gives negative imaginary part with unary plus, as in -0.266+-0.082i, which is a valid complex number format in Google Sheets as well.

Ungolfed:
=let( 
  s, A1^2 + B1^2, 
  a, atan2(A1, B1), 
  r, s^(C1 / 2) / exp(D1 * a), 
  u, C1 * a + D1 * ln(s) / 2, 
  { r * cos(u), r * sin(u) } 
)

-5 bytes thanks to Arnauld.
The same in JavaScript (non-competing, 102 bytes):
with(Math)f=(a,b,c,d,s=a*a+b*b,p=atan2(b,a),r=s**(c/2)/exp(d*p),u=c*p+d*log(s)/2)=>[r*cos(u),r*sin(u)]


Can you save a byte with /exp(1)^(D1*a)?

Or just /exp(D1*a) -- unless I'm missing something.

@Arnauld thanks for noting the oversight.

Although Google Sheets is automatically turning .5 into 0.5, I think this should still count as 97 bytes.

@Arnauld sorry, there's meta consensus that auto-completed bits like that zero and closing parentheses & quotes still count (as does the leading =. Interestingly, the results of the two formulas differ in the 16th decimal.

Thank you for pointing this out. I've added another answer to the first linked meta topic, as I think the currently accepted one is not clear enough.

@Arnauld did a quick test to find whether Google Sheets autocompletion takes place in the formula editor or the formula parser. range.setFormula('=sum(1, 2') works but gives a parse error in the cell. If you add the missing closing paren in the code or the cell it works fine. So there: autocompletion is an "IDE" feature in Google Sheets.

Did you test "0.5" abbreviated to ".5"? That's the one we're interested in here.

@Arnauld wow, your hunch is correct. .5 does get autocompleted by the parser. range.setFormula('=sum(1, .5)') results in =sum(1, 0.5).

APL (Dyalog Unicode), 87 71 bytes
Anonymous infix lambda taking [a,b] as left argument, [c,d] as right argument, and returning [x,y] for \$x+yi\$.
{(*-/⍵×⌽p)×2 1○+/⍵×p←({0=⍺:○.5××⍵⋄(¯3○⍵÷⍺)+○(0>⍺)×¯1*0>⍵}/⍺),.5×⍟+/⍺×⍺}

Try it online!
{…} is an anonymous lambda with ⍺ as left argument and ⍵ as right argument.
The only operations used (and only on reals) are:

× multiplication
infix + addition
prefix ⍟ natural logarithm
infix × multiplication
infix , concatenation
f/ f-reduction
…:…⋄… ternary (if … then … else …)
infix = equality
prefix × sign
prefix ○ pi times
infix > greater than
infix * exponentiation
infix ÷ division
prefix ¯3○ arctangent
infix ← assignment
prefix 2 1○ cosine and sine
prefix ⌽ reverse list
infix - subtraction
prefix * exponential

Note that there's no atan2 on the list. I implement it as \$\text{atan2}(a,b)=\big(\tan^{-1}\frac{b}a\big)+\pi\Big(\frac{(1-2[0>b])\,\text{sgn}\,a}2-[0>b]\Big)\$

doesn't agree with * (nor wolframalpha) for ¯1 1 1 1, i think the problem is that you're using arctan instead of atan2

@RubenVerg Implemented atan2 now.

Google Sheets, 87 bytes
Expects \$a\$, \$b\$, \$c\$, \$d\$ in \$A1\$, \$B1\$, \$C1\$, \$D1\$ respectively and it returns the result in two horizontally adjacent cells.
=LET(a,LN(A1^2+B1^2)/2,b,ATAN2(A1,B1),c,EXP(C1*a-D1*b),d,C1*b+D1*a,{c*COS(d),c*SIN(d)})



Python, 107 bytes
lambda a,b,c,d:[g(c*(p:=atan2(b,a))+d*log(h:=hypot(a,b)))*h**c/exp(d*p)for g in[cos,sin]]
from math import*

Attempt This Online!
A port of Arnaulds JS answer

Python 3, 89 bytes
import math
e=lambda a,b,c,d:math.e**((c+1j*d)*(math.log(a**2+b**2)/2+1j*math.atan2(b,a)))

Try it online

-10 chars:
lambda a,b,c,d:e**((c+1j*d)*(log(a**2+b**2)/2+1j*atan2(b,a))) (\n) from math import*

Nice, but c+1j*d looks like it violates "Built-in complex arithmetic is not allowed"?

Looking back, it does.

I see, that's unfortunate :(. I found a 108 bytes, but I don't think less than 107 is doable.

Python + numpy, 115 bytes
-9 bytes thanks to corvus_192
lambda x,y:[(e:=exp(linalg.det([y,t:=[arctan2(*x[::-1]),log(hypot(*x))]])))*cos(y@t),e*sin(y@t)]
from numpy import*

Attempt This Online!
If someone has a trick to remove a few of these 12 pairs of brackets...
Explanation
To compute (a + i b) ** (c + i d), it is helpful to have the two quantities
c log(norm(a,b)) - d atan2(b,a)
c atan2(b,a) + d log(norm(a,b))

It turns out that withy = (c,d) and t = (atan2(b,a), log(norm(a,b))):

the first is the determinant det([y,t]), and
the second is the dot product y@t.


115 bytes: lambda x,y:[(e:=exp(linalg.det([y,t:=[arctan2(*x[::-1]),log(hypot(*x))]])))*cos(y@t),e*sin(y@t)];from numpy import*

@corvus_192 Thanks! 2 pairs down, 12 to go!
